# CQRS to command or not to, that is the question

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am new to CQRS, but can see the value in this, so I am trying to apply this to a financial system that we are busy rebuilding.

Like I mentioned, this is a basic fin system with basic balance, withdraw, deposit like functionality.

I have a withdraw & deposit commands. But I am struggling with balance.

According to the domain experts, they want to handle balance as a transaction, with no financial implication (yet), on the clients behalf. So, when the client does a balance inq via the device, it creates a transaction, but also a balance query at the same time.

In the CQRS world, you distiguish between commands that mutate state & queries, that retrieve data in some way.

Apologies if my understanding here are flawed. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

EDIT:
Maybe let me put it this way. I was thinking of creating a CheckBalanceCommand that creates a transaction & insert a BalanceCheckedEvent into the store. But then I would also need to create a CheckBalanceQuery to retrieve the actual balance from the read db.
I would need to invoke both in order to satisfy the balance request.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting issue. Your business case is valid: some commands don't mutate aggregate/entity states, still treating them and their resultant events are important (e.g. for audit trails).

In order to support these cases, I'd introduce a base event type named `IdentityEvent` (inspired by identity values for various mathematical operators and as a justification for the concept; operating them on a certain value doesn't change it). On issuing the corresponding command, derivatives of this event (e.g. `BalanceCheckedEvent` in your case) will be appended to the aggregate's event stream and view projection may construct views from them as usual; however, their mutate method will *not perform any actual mutation* while reconstructing entities from event stream.

The actual command processing takes place at the *domain layer*. Some of your *application service*, at the *application layer*, receives the query request, processes it as usual. Additionally, before or after the query operation, the same application service may issue the command to the domain layer, on the aggregate root itself. That doesn't violate any principle: your *read and query model are still separate*, application service just *coordinating between the two*.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as rare as you would imagine. An additional valid business case is when a service provider runs a credit check on someone. Credit reporting companies actually store queries made against ones credit score, and use it to influence future credit scores. Of course, when I say that this isn't as rare as we imagine, I'm not attempting to normalize such practices (and we should push back to understand the real value something like this is offering to our product).

What I suggest though is to model this explicitly and not try to generalize this. This feature probably is driven by some business need, and you should model it as such. By this I mean that you should treat the service serving the reads as a separate service entirely, which can raise it's own events for things that have happened, and design the rest of the system in a reactive way (ie responding to events generated by another BC/service).

As an example, you could have the service which serves the query fire a BalanceChecked event, which either the same service or another one could store in a stream for subsequent processing.

I would not suggest a command, because if you'll be replying with the data it's not as if someone can reject the command; it has already happened, someone already has the data.